# kubectl run mypod --image=myimage - ErrImagePull

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-image

I'm trying to run some docker images on Kubernetes.

docker images

```bash
master* $ docker images                                              [15:16:49]                                                                                
REPOSITORY                    TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
usm                           latest        4dd5245393bf   About an hour ago   158MB
kuard                         latest        497961f486c7   4 days ago          22.9MB
```

docker container

```bash
master* $ docker ps                                                  [15:21:40]
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
a46850d28303   usm                                   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:6061->80/tcp, :::6061->80/tcp                                                                                                  usm
88471e086486   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.32   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   2 days ago          Up 2 hours         127.0.0.1:49157->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49156->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49155->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49154->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49153->32443/tcp   minikube
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

kube version

```bash
master* $ minikube version                                           [15:37:13]
minikube version: v1.26.0
commit: f4b412861bb746be73053c9f6d2895f12cf78565
```

When I run `kubectl run mypod --image=usm`, I get **ErrImagePull**

How to run the pod with the local docker image?

```bash
master* $ kubectl run mypod --image=usm
pod/mypod created
```

```bash
master* $ kubectl get pods                                           [15:07:49]
NAME    READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
mypod   0/1     ErrImagePull   0          6s
```

I'm trying to set the imagePullPolicy to never

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: usm
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    name: mypod
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
```

```bash
master* $ kubectl apply -f kube-pod-usm.yaml                         [15:55:39]
pod/mypod created
```

```bash
master* $ kubectl get pods                                           [15:55:54]
NAME    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
mypod   0/1     ErrImageNeverPull   0          42s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that image to be available in someplace. Normally this is done through a registry, but for local development, you can just upload your local image to your minikukbe cluster with the following command:

`minikube image load image:tag`

You may also want to check `minikube docker-env` which allows pointing your terminal docker-cli to the docker inside minikube in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

When a Kubernetes cluster creates a new deployment or updates an existing deployment, it needs to pull an image. This is done through the kubelet process on each user node. In order for kubelets to pull this image successfully, they must be accessible from all nodes in the cluster that match the scheduling request.

**Edit pod specification and provide the correct registry**

If you set the Image pull Policy to Never :
the kubelet does not try fetching the image. If the image is somehow already present locally (in the local registry of Kubernetes), the kubelet attempts to start the container; otherwise, startup fails.